# How to import a file with json object to another js file?

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I have a js file with values. Usually, i export it from that data js file to another file.
But currently, i am getting error as i am trying to export file which has json object.
Usually, i will import by

```
var Category=require('./filmdata.js');
```

or

```
import Category from './filmdata.js';
```

Currently, I'm using first method since second method also showed error as `"Cannot use import statement outside a module"`  And second method now shows,

```
var price = [
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
```

My json object file looks something like this.

```
exports.Category={
price : [
    {"film":
        {F: [a,b,c],
        I: [d,e,f],
        L: [g,h,i],}
}
],
```

What can i change here to import this json object to my file? Thanks in advance.

Update: I missed out to say that i also have about 5 arrays in the same js file.
As per answers provided, i tried with only json object and exported it and it worked. But, i am unable to export and use it elsewhere, if i have arrays aong with json object. my data.js looks something like,

```
exports.Category={
    price : [
        {"film":
            {F: [a,b,c],
            I: [d,e,f],
            L: [g,h,i],}
    }
    ],
   let arr1=[F,I,L],
   let arr2=[10,20,50],
   let arr3=[A,U,I],
   let arr4=[2,5,10],
   minimumvalue=2,
   maximumvalue=5000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Inside js object keyvalue pairs must have `:` not `=`

index.js

```
exports.data = {
price: [
    {
      "film":
      {
        F: [`a`, `b`, `c`],
        I: [`d`, `e`, `f`],
        L: [`g`, `h`, `i`],
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

read.js

```
// const data = require('./index').data;

// or

const {data} = require('./index');

console.log(data.price)
```

Comment: I changed the colon but still getting an error as module not found.  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Comment: Did you try with the examples that I have given. Copy paste this example and check

Comment: Yes, i have tried those as it is. But, getting error as module not found. It seems there are some other issues.I am not sure where this is going wrong.is there any chance that webdriverio plugins might be an issue? I used map array function and got the another error. ReferenceError: map is not defined

Comment: var pricemap = new map(
 [  [F,[a,b,c]],
 [I,[d,e,f]],
 [L:[g,h,i]]
 ]);                                     This is what i used last, trying to use it as map array, but got a referenceerror.

Comment: You  don't have too use map for just exporting. Map is used to do some modification to all elements in a array. Example add 5 to each element in that array.

Comment: i am just storing a table value as Map and exporting it into another js file for some validation purpose. Since, i got lots of error with json object, i tried with map. even then , i am getting error with exporting and importing. not sure if there is something different in webdriverio

Comment: Did you try the screenshot which has import and export of json?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry that i missed out to say that along with json i am giving 5 array values too in this js file. I tried to use exactly as you said with only json. it worked. the problem however is, when i give array of data in the same js file. it shows as ':' expected, i guess it considers all data as json object here including the arrays.

Comment: Please update the question with your current code. So, That I can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You're mistake is how you're assigning the `price` variable in `filmdata.js`. Since the variable is in an object, you must use a colon to assign it a value: `price: <value>`.

So `filmdata.js` would be something like:

```js
exports.Category={
  price: [{
    "film": {
       F: [1, 2, 3],
       I: [4, 5, 6],
       L: [9, 8, 7],
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And whatever other data comes after it.

Comment: I changed the colon but still getting an error as module not found.  
  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^